# Why AsRef can not be used as parameter type annotation but fine with generic declaration?

Tags: rust

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28f7cd87b9267fd939330bdd461ba533)

```rust
use std::path::Path;

// fn f1(p: AsRef<Path>) {
//     println!("{}", p.as_ref().display());
// }

fn f2<P: AsRef<Path>>(p: P) {
    println!("{}", p.as_ref().display());
}

fn main() {
    f2("/tmp/test.jpg");
}
```

The compiler will complain about the size of Path is not known for f1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AsRef` is a trait, not a type. Your definition of `f1()` uses it in place of a type. This legacy syntax is short for `dyn AsRef<Path>`, and denotes an arbitrary type implementing the trait `AsRef<Path>`, with dynamic dispatch at runtime. The size of an arbitrary type implementing the trait obviously isn't known at compile time, so you can use trait objects only behind pointers, e.g. `&dyn AsRef<Path>` or `Box<dyn AsRef<Path>>`. The compiler does not complain about the size of `Path` being unknown, it complains about the size of the trait object being unknown.

Trait bounds on generic types, on the other hand, expect traits, not types. `P` again is an arbitrary type implementing `AsRef<Path>`, but this arbitrary type needs to be known at compile time, and the compiler emits a new compiled version of `f2()` for every type that is actually used. This way, the size of each individual type is known at compile time.

Comment: Thanks so much for this excellent explanation. I can understand how generic works here now.